# Fixing a note on my guitar

Tags: guitar, tuning

I'm tuning my guitar and the second string is playing a D, should I loosen it or tighten it in order to get it to the right note?

Comment: How do you know it's playing a D? If you're using an electronic tuner, it will often tell you if the played note is too high or low.

Answer (score 2):

(Note that this answer assumes the standard E-A-D-G-B-E tuning.)

Guitar strings are numbered from highest pitch to lowest pitch; thus the high E string is the first string, the B string the second string, all the way to the low E string which is the sixth string.

Within a single string, increasing the tension leads to a higher pitch, and decreasing the tensions lowers the pitch.

Thus if your second string (the B string) is playing a D, you want to lower the pitch by *loosening* the string.

(Now, I guess it's *possible* that the D that's being played is the farther away D that's below the B that you want, and you'll actually want to tighten the string to raise it up...but I find this pretty unlikely.)

Comment: Not criticising at all - but isn't it confusing when we say standard tuning is E-A-D-G-B-e, and then number the strings the opposite way. This could be a rhetorical question/statement, except I don't know the answer...

Comment: I agree, I've always thought it was a little silly as well.

Comment: I get my beginner pupils to come up with a 6 word sentence - often daft, but each word starts with e,B,G,D,A,and E in THAT order.